# rails security: converting parameters to symbols for hash lookup

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a hash of constants I refer to throughout my code like:

```
CATEGORIES = {
  business:  '1002',
  education:  '1003',
  entertainment:  '1004',
  # etc...
}
```

In one of my controllers I need to test for the existing of a category via parameter, so normally I'd do something like:

```
CATEGORIES.has_key? params[:category].to_sym
```

However that seems like an invitation to a denial of service attack, as an attacker could easily blow up the Ruby symbol table by providing random strings for `category` params.

Seems like the easiest solution is to convert the `CATEGORY` keys to strings rather than symbols:

```
CATEGORIES = {
  'business' =>  '1002',
  'education' =>  '1003',
  'entertainment' =>  '1004',
  # etc...
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
def self.valid_category(category_s)
   CATEGORIES.keys.any? { |key| key.to_s == category_s }
end
```

Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a better or more idiomatic way to do this in Rails?

The most common approach I've seen is the second solution you provided, i.e.:

```
def self.valid_category(category_s)
  CATEGORIES.keys.any? { |key| key.to_s == category_s }
end
```

Although, I would name the method `self.valid_category?`. Maybe I would also move the .to_s on the category variable to this method, so something like:

```
def self.valid_category?(category)
  category = category.to_s
  CATEGORIES.keys.any? { |key| key.to_s == category }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just check if `params[:category]` is in [`CATEGORIES.values`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html#method-i-values). I don't see why you need to be worrying about the hash keys in this case... it looks like they are just for readability.

```
params[:category].in? CATEGORIES.values
```

or

```
CATEGORIES.values.include? params[:category]
```

I should mention that `in?` is provided by ActiveSupport, while `include?` is provided by the Ruby standard lib.

Comment: It's the hash keys that represent categories, not their values. Testing whether the key exists is validation that the category exists.

Comment: Fair enough, I misunderstood. I think using strings as the keys is a good solution then.